# Examples of Master/Detail reports for Rave for Delphi 2007 using sub-totals

Tags: delphi-2007, rave-reports

I want to create a report using Rave for Delphi 2007 where one column is sub-totaled for each group of records, and then a grand total is also shown.  Are there any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will find a simple test project based on xampp cdcol db as data source for simple reports, and an id grouped report with jahr subtotals for each id and a a grand total.

Download CBuilder source at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIDI2WGrvVBTUN4X1F1d2dmRVE/edit?usp=sharing